# Can someone explain this CSS code to me?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work on adjusting the size of a picture from a web page.

My friend wrote something, and I am trying to learn from it. What does this code do?

```
div.page-full-width div#primary div#content div.entry-content    div#bbpress-forums div.bbp-reply-form form#new-post fieldset.bbp-form div p.bbp-attachments-form label.btn {
    width: 9vw;
    height: 1vw;
}


.entry-buddypress-content div#buddypress div.full-width div#item-body div.profile div#subnav {
    width: 21vw !important;
    height: 8vw !important;
    padding-right: 2vw !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#members-stream li .action div.generic-button a, #members-list li .action div.generic-button a {
    font-size: 3vw;
    line-height: 4vw;
}
```

some are `#`, some are `.` and some are `div.`, how do they work to target specific lines from HTML code?

Comment: Makes the elements taller/shorter and wider/thinner based on the users device (`vw`)

Answer (score 2):

`#foo` selects the element with the id `foo`. ([See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors))

`.bar` selects all elements with the class `bar`. ([See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors))

[More about CSS selectors in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: sorry, can you use the code I provided to explain to me? if you can simply use the div.page one to explain to me a little clearer

Comment: You should really have a look at the guide I linked. This will make things a lot clearer. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask them on SO.

Comment: what if the HTML is nested in bunch of div class and id?      
 `<div id="content" role="main">
               <div class="cqg-hp-container">
                    <img class="cqg-hp-img-search" src="http://wp.com">
                    <div class="last-name-search-page">
                         <div>
                              <form method="post" action="http://wp.com/search-results/" id="searchform"> 
                                   <input type="text" name="searchval" value="" placeholder="请输入关键字"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>`
and what I try to edit is the input type line?

Comment: You could use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the `input` based on the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`.test` is for classes in html 
`#test` is for Ids in html 
`div.` selectes all divs with this classname

Width: 9vw means view width so the image is 9% of the view width

He basically selected with this css a lot of Ids and Classes and gives them a height, width, distance inside(padding), distance outside(margin), font size and the line height(on which height the text should be displayed).

Hope this helps